# how to read header value to resolve method dynamically in service activator

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I went through a spring blog which explains about dynamically routing with groovy.

I am setting `method` header value in previous service activator

```
    <int:service-activator input-channel="routingChannel"
        output-channel="headerRouter" ref="routingHelper"  method="headers['method']">
   </int:service-activator>
```

I have tried

1. headers.get('method') -> which is throwing no suitable method to handle messages error.
2. `expression="@beanFactory.getBean('routingHelper').routeMe()` also not working

please help me in getting header values in config xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work that way.

You can use in the `method` argument only `bean definition phase` expressions. This one (`headers['method'`) runtime type and can be used really from those attributes which is with `expression` word. But it won't help anyway: SpEL doesn't have `method-invocation-by-name` notation.

From other side need to understand your logic. What is the reason to router by method name if you end up with the reflection?

Why just don't do that using the single method and `if...else` inside? Or make routing to different beans.

Even with the Groovy dynamic method invocation we end up with reflection:

```
routingHelper.'headers[method]'(payload)
```

Comment: Hi Artem, thanks for your reply :) i read the spring forum thread which explains calling of service activator dynamically , service-activator input-channel="inputChannel" output-channel="outputChannel"
                       expression="@beanFactory.getBean(headers.serviceIdentifier + 'Service').execute(headers, payload)"/

Comment: but it is also throwing error :@beanFactory.getBean(headers.method).routeMe(payload) :  nested exception is org.springframework.expression.AccessException: Could not resolve bean reference against BeanFactory

Comment: That's correct because you try to invoke something from this `headers.method` where it is just method name, but you need exactly service for the method, which can be the same for all your particular services - the same interface.